# How to express "to arrive on the ship" in Italian

Tags: translation, prepositions, phrase-request

How would one say "she arrives on the ship" in Italian? Google Translate gives me "lei arriva sulla nave" but I was told that "lei arriva in nave" or "lei arriva con la nave" would be more usual. I think that "lei arriva in nave" is in fact a translation of "she arrives *by* ship ?

Comment: Apparently those who told you so misunderstood the English sentence, or else I am doing so now. “She arrives on the ship” means that earlier she wasn't on board and now she is about to: correct? If that's the case, then Google is unexpectedly right, while the other two versions mean indeed “...by ship”.

Comment: That seems a valid interpretation, but the intended meaning is that the person is arriving somewhere (eg New York) aboard a specific ship. I could have made that clear with a slightly different sentence, eg "Every Christmas she arrives at New York on the ship X"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"She arrives on the ship" is somewhat ambiguous.

"She arrives on the ship" (the act of arriving has the ship as its object) would be "arriva sulla nave" (or "sale a bordo" or "si imbarca").

"She arrives on the ship" (the act of arriving has the ship as its means) might also be "arriva sulla nave" (or more likely, "sarà sulla nave"), but is usually rendered as "arriva con la nave" (you can then specify which: "arriva con il traghetto delle 15:50", "arriva con la Costa Splendida"), "arriva per nave" (arrives on a ship, you might not know which exactly), this last being the same as "arriva via nave" which, to my ears, sounds better.

(You might also perhaps say "sarà sulla nave", or even "sbarcherà" :-) )